# Convert lowercase in ARM THUMB Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

```
arr1    DCB    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
arr2    DCB     0,   0,   0,   0,   0

loop
        MOV    R0, #0       ;loop counter
        MOV    R1, #arr1    ;store arr1 in R1
        MOV    R2, #arr2    ;store arr2 in R2
        CMP    R0, #4       
        BEQ    finish
        LSR    R2, R1, #1
        SUB    R2, R1, #32  
        ADD    R0, R0, #1
        B      loop

finish  END
```

I am very new to assembly language, trying to convert the chars in arr1 to uppercase and then store them in the address of arr2.

I know how to convert it using ASCII values like in Java, Python but having trouble doing it in ARM THUMB using a loop. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You set `R0` to 4, then immediately test if it equals 4, and if it is then you exit...?

Comment: Also, you have no load or store instructions in your code, so you will never read anything from `arr1` nor write anything to `arr2`.  The registers R1 and R2 contain the addresses of those arrays, not the data stored at those addresses.

Comment: @NateEldredge and How do I access the data stored at those addresses. Say I want to subtract 32 from the arr[1] and store that in arr2[i]. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: `ldrb` to load the byte into a register, `sub` to do the subtraction, `strb` to store it in the new location.  So for instance if you have the correct index `i` in `r0`, I think you can `ldrb r3, [r1, r0] ; sub r3, #32 ; strb r3, [r2, r0]`.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Clarifying, this is not a HW problem.